# Oracle data pump

Tags: oracle

I am using Oracle Export data pump (expdp) for my application . My oracle client and server are on different machines . When I use my application which is on the oracle client machine , the exported dump is always created on the Oracle server machine . Is this the oracle export data pump limitation ? Or Is there a workaround ?

Answer (score 2):

thats the way datapump works by design.

If you need client side, you have to use the older `exp` and `imp`. otherwise use datapump and ftp the file to your local machine afterwards.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm#i1010293

> Note: All Data Pump Export and Import processing, including the
>   reading and writing of dump files, is done on the system (server)
>   selected by the specified database connect string. This means that for
>   unprivileged users, the database administrator (DBA) must create
>   directory objects for the Data Pump files that are read and written on
>   that server file system.

Comment: @Dazzal I was expecting this answer :)  But i am not sure if ftp from a production machine would be enabled

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar then you'd have to use `exp` and `imp` as they are the client-side tool.